# Facebook API: Unknown fields: name?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

My request:

```
<FBRequestConnection: 0x93a8ba0, 1 request(s):(
<FBRequest: 0x9395c90, session: 0xa8aeb80, graphPath: https://graph.facebook.com/me, HTTPMethod: GET, parameters:
{
   "access_token" = BAAG4P63ZBHK0BAObimWrMZCGOzn3s6qOtqynyzkJmIN0fKiKGlCkmlqlKMcpbvrrhN9QJsIxrTc7PZCFoceuCwAC2ygCph27WV72iwxkbi2svKCDemDo8BBqOwc6bp6DQH7U9tjp4gZBofb4brYg;
   fields = name;
   format = json;
   "migration_bundle" = "fbsdk:20120913";
   sdk = ios;
})>
```

My response:

```
result (null)
error Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x93b1ad0 {com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 100;
            message = "(#100) Unknown fields: name.";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400}
```

What is the reason behind?
If I send without **fields = name;** then I get back some default user data.

---

Invoking:

```
FBRequest *graphRequest = [[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:[FBSession activeSession]
                                                   graphPath:request.graphPath
                                                  parameters:request.parameters
                                                  HTTPMethod:request.httpMethod];

FBRequestConnection *connection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];
[connection addRequest:graphRequest
     completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
 {
     [self requestCompleted:connection result:result error:error];
 }];
[connection start];
```

Request object:

```
-(NSString*)graphPath
{ return @"https://graph.facebook.com/me"; }

-(NSDictionary*)parameters
{
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            @"name", @"fields",
            nil];
}

-(NSString*)HTTPMethod
{
    return @"GET";
}
```

---

Have tried with fixed parametes as well, no effect:

```
graphRequest = [[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:[FBSession activeSession]
                                        graphPath:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me"
                                       parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"name", @"fields", nil]
                                       HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
```

Comment: Could you share code for the original request that is logging this request/response?

Comment: Actually a started FBRequestConnection with an FBRequest code inside with the parameters above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graph path must be relative.
Now I use only **@"me"** instead of @"https://graph.facebook.com/me", and works like a charm.